# Prove every strongly connected tournament has a cycle of length k for k = 3, 4, … n where n is the number of vertices.

Tags: graph-theory

Prove every strongly connected tournament has a cycle of length $k$ for $k = 3, 4,  … n$ where $n$ is the number of vertices.

I know that I need to prove this thm by induction but I am not sure how.

Answer (score 7):

I suppose you already know that a strongly connected tournament of order $n\gt1$ must contain a $3$-cycle. (If the tournament has no $3$-cycle, it's a transitive tournament, and not strongly connected.) For the induction step you have to show that, given a $k$-cycle (where $3\le k\lt n$), you can construct a $(k+1)$-cycle.

Consider a $k$-cycle $C=\{u_0,\dots,u_{k-1}\}$ with arcs $u_iu_{i+1}$ (addition modulo $k$).

**Case I.** For some vertex $v\notin C$ there is an arc from $C$ to $v$ and there is also an arc from $v$ to $C$.

Then for some $i\in\{0,\dots,k-1\}$ there are arcs $u_iv$ and $vu_{i+1}$. We get a cycle on the vertex set $C\cup\{v\}$, replacing the arc $u_iu_{i+1}$ with the arcs $u_iv$ and $vu_{i+1}$.

**Case II.** For each vertex $v\notin C$, either all arcs between $C$ and $v$ are directed from $C$ to $v$, or alse all arcs between $C$ and $v$ are directed from $v$ to $C$.

Let $V$ be the set of all vertices $v$ such that all arcs between $C$ and $v$ are directed from $C$ to $v$, and let $W$ be the set of all vertices $w$ such that all arcs between $C$ and $w$ are directed from $w$ to $C$.

Since the tournament is strongly connected (and $k\lt n$), the sets $V$ and $W$ are nonempty, and there is at least one arc $vw$ with $v\in V$ and $w\in W$.  Then $\{u_0,\dots,u_{k-2},v,w\}$ is a $(k+1)$-cycle.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a very detailed proof in [this paper page 15 theorem 4](http://www.math.cmu.edu/~af1p/Teaching/GT/CH10.pdf)