# A cycle of length $l$ and less in a tournament

Tags: graph-theory

For an $l$ cycle in a tournament I want to show that the tournament has $s$-cycle for $s=3,4...l$.

My guess  that If you have a cycle of length $l$ in a tournament then by transiviting   two arcs into one we get a smaller cycle down to a triangle.

Comment: Essentially the same as [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1233862/prove-every-strongly-connected-tournament-has-a-cycle-of-length-k-for-k-3-4) since we can just look at the $l$-vertex tournament induced by the cycle.